# Java HtmlUnit - Get Twitter results

Tags: java, search, twitter, htmlunit

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit to load a Twitter page, but it seems it's not processing the javascript code correctly.
Java code:

```
String url_web= "https://twitter.com/search?q=from:BillGates";
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url_web);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    System.out.println(page.asXml());
}
```

The code returns html content, but not the same displayed on browser, its not including the tweets itself. I'm using the latest HtmlUnit version 2.47.1.

Comment: Will have a look, maybe related to scrolling and the rendering depends on some layout events. But twitter uses a lot of javascript - it will be not that simple.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you RBRi, surely the issue is because some javascripts used by Twitter are not yet supported by HtmlUnit.